# Werkzeug/flask application logs

Tags: flask, logging, stdout, gunicorn, werkzeug

I am trying to get the default logs seen on terminal emulator on my local machine which works well. However, on centos server I cannot get an output to the log file when I restart the Gunicorn service. The logs I desire are shown below: my work around was to get the logs on the shell while in the virtual environment:

```
[2023-10-21 18:01:38,550] INFO in _internal:  * Restarting with stat
[2023-10-21 18:01:39,049] WARNING in _internal:  * Debugger is active!
[2023-10-21 18:01:39,052] INFO in _internal:  * Debugger PIN: 691-655-964
[2023-10-21 18:58:06,111] INFO in _internal: [31m[1mWARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://10.200.16.168:5000
[2023-10-21 18:58:06,111] INFO in _internal: [33mPress CTRL+C to quit[0m
[2023-10-21 18:58:06,111] INFO in _internal:  * Restarting with stat
[2023-10-21 18:58:06,691] WARNING in _internal:  * Debugger is active!
[2023-10-21 18:58:06,707] INFO in _internal:  * Debugger PIN: 691-655-964
[2023-10-21 19:01:45,844] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2023 19:01:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[2023-10-21 19:01:45,917] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2023 19:01:45] "[36mGET /static/media/Ericsson_logo.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 304 -
[2023-10-21 19:01:46,068] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Oct/2023 19:01:46] "[36mGET /static/jqueryAdd.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 304 -
```

And this is my configuration in the server:

````
import os
import logging
import logging.handlers
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash
from datetime import timedelta


from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'file.handler': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'server_werkzeug.log',
            'maxBytes': 10000000,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'werkzeug': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['file.handler'],
        },
    },
})

#logging.basicConfig(filename='flask_record.log', level=logging.INFO, format=f'%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(threadName)s : %(message)s')

app = Flask(__name__)```
````